# Android: Perform actions on a ShapeDrawable within an ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview

I have created a ShapeDrawable and placed it within an imageview that is dynamically created within my layout. Here's the code I use to assign the drawable to my ImageView. Notice that I call on a method to set a random color, I also set the height and width using user filled text fields, but that's irrelevant here.

```
ShapeDrawable shape;

public void makeShape(){

    shape = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    shape.setIntrinsicHeight(Integer.parseInt(ET_Height.getText().toString()));
    shape.setIntrinsicWidth(Integer.parseInt(ET_Width.getText().toString()));
    shape.getPaint().setColor(chooseColor());
    iView.setImageDrawable(shape);
}
```

This part of the code works wonderfully, it's when I later try and access the Drawable to change it's color on a user click, utilizing the same color method from before.

```
public void onClick(View v){

    iView.getDrawable().getPaint().setColor(chooseColor());
}
```

Obviously this code doesn't work, but it's the closest I have come to being able to complete it. I can't access the drawable via "shape" either, and I don't understand why.

So what's the best way to gain access to the drawable to change it's color, alpha, rotation, etc in the onClick method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iView.setImageDrawable(shape) again after changing the **shape** parameters.

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm attempting to call the same random color generator code on the existing shape but it's not changing anything.

Comment: Ok. Did you try creating a new shape drawable and setting it again in the image view instead of just changing the color?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Abhinav's solution to this same problem and it worked for me
Basicly useing the same parameters I Used to create the shape then just created the same shape again and set color and bounds to the existing shape